# Using TooltipService.Tooltip Keyword in a Resource Dictionary for UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm translating my UWP app via x: UID property like this.

**Code (XAML):**

```
<NavigationViewItem  x:Name="Assistant_Mode" x:Uid="Assistant_Header" Content="Asistan modu" Tag="assistant" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Asistan modu." FontFamily="Segoe UI">
```

**Resource Dictionary record:**

> Assistant_Header.Content: Asistan modu

Now, I want translate the ToolTipService.ToolTip via Resource dictionary but this keyboard is not work in Dictionary:

> Assistant_Header.ToolTipService.ToolTip: Asistan modu

Can I transalte a Tooltip in a Resource Dictionary ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something you may need to notice is that official recommend way is described in [ResourceDictionary and localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#resourcedictionary-and-localization):

*A XAML ResourceDictionary might initially contain strings that are to be localized. If so, store these strings as project resources instead of in a ResourceDictionary. Take the strings out of the XAML, and instead give the owning element an x:Uid directive value. Then, define a resource in a resources file. Provide a resource name in the form XUIDValue.PropertyName and a resource value of the string that should be localized.*

If changing with this way still does not work, what about put the x:uid to the textbox inside ToolTipService.ToolTip, like the following code:

```
    <Button Content="Button with a simple ToolTip." >
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock x:Uid="test" Text="123456"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Barry Wang.

Comment: This is possible directly with special syntax for attached properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-xaml-markup

Answer (score 10):

There's special syntax for referencing attached properties for Uid.

In XAML (as normal):

`<Button x:Uid="MyControl"/>`

Then in your resw file use key:

`MyControl.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip`

See [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-xaml-markup).

Comment: Be aware that in Microsoft WinUI 3 namespace for tooltips was changed to [using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls]

Comment: "MyControl. ToolTipService. ToolTip" also can work.